# remove redundancy in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following in my .htaccess:
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /demotut/

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /demotut/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.*)$ $1.php [L] 


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ $1.php [L]
```

This works for me. The code is suppose to do the following:
 1. if a request comes in at : 'host/demotut',  then redirect to 'host/demotut/index.php'
 2. if a request comes in at : 'host/demotut/somefile',  then redirect to 'host/demotut/somefile.php'
 3. if a request comes in at : 'host/demotut/somefile/and/urllike/vars',  then redirect to 'host/demotut/somefile.php/and/urllike/vars'

The files in the root of the website act as controllers. As I said this actually works, but the repeating statements bother me.

I played with the [L], and commenting out the RewriteRule, but this is the only way I got it to work.

is there anyway to compact this?